# how to check users online

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, session-timeout

I'm using Java EE (EJB, JPA, JSF) and JBoss. How can I check online users? Of course, I have User entity. And user can login and logout. I thought we can check the session that created when a user login. But when that session times out, how do we know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)**, it receives notification when an HTTP session is activated or is about to be deactivated.

In order to receive these notification events, the implementation class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web application or annotated with WebListener.

There are two methods declared in the HttpSessionListener interface which must be implemented by the servlet programmer to perform some action.

1. **public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e)** : is invoked when
   session object is created.
2. **public void sessionDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e)** : is invoked when session is invalidated.

[Here](http://www.javatpoint.com/HttpSessionEvent) you can get an tutorial for implementation.

Comment: In this case you need to wait for session expiration.

Comment: I have one more question. When a user visits my web, there are more one session created. How do we identify which session need to count, which not?

Comment: When you create new session, you can invalidate old session by calling invalidate method. I don't think that more than one session is necessary for one user.

Comment: Maybe, i have a misunderstanding. I used a bean(CDI bean, Session Scope) for user to login. I used another bean (CDI bean, session scope) for a form (the form for user send feedback to me). I thought, at least there are two sessions created.

Comment: What method you are using for creating session?

Comment: I used a CDI bean for login(session Scoped). I thought, when that bean called and executed, a session created. Because, that bean has session scope. Right?